# How does tf.keras.layers.Dense work on 3D tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a 3D tensor containing a batch of sentences. Therefore the shape is [batch size, number of words in the sentence, embedding dimension]. In a toy example I'm working on the actual dimension is [256, 84, 32]. Note, in this example I zero pad the number of words in the sentences. I want to pass this tensor through a dense layer using tf.keras.layers.Dense. I defined the dense layer as `dense=tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)`. However when I send the 3D tensor to this dense layer I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Tensor's shape (128, 128) is not compatible with supplied shape [32, 32]
```

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: when I reshape the 3D tensor to (256, 84*32) and then feed it to a dense=tf.keras.layers.Dense(84*32) I still get the following error:
ValueError: Tensor's shape (128, 128) is not compatible with supplied shape [2688, 2688]

Comment: Can you check whether you put the right input to Dense layer, where input Tensor's shape (128, 128) while your 3D tensor input is [256, 84, 32]?